# My XSD does not validate the XML despite proper namespace declarations

Tags: java, xml, validation, namespaces, xsd

The XSD `<schema>` tag:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
    targetNamespace="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

The root of the XML, `<people>` tag.

```
<people
    xmlns="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank student.xsd">
```

How ever I get en error that:

```
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'people'
```

I know it has something to do with namespaces but I can not figure out what.

**Please help**

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "validator.dtd"> -->


    <people
        xmlns="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank student.xsd"> 

        <student>
            <name>John</name>
            <course>Computer Technology</course>
            <semester>6</semester>
            <scheme>E</scheme>
        </student>

        <student>
            <name>Foo</name>
            <course>Industrial Electronics</course>
            <semester>6</semester>
            <scheme>E</scheme>
        </student>
    </people>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
        targetNamespace="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="people">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="student" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="course" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="semester">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="1" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="2" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="3" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="4" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="5" />
                                        <xs:enumeration value="6" />
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="scheme">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern value = "E|C" />
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Is student XSD in the same folder with your XML? It also seems that your namespace support in your parser may be turned off(?) since the error message implies `people` in no namespace, while it is obviously qualified...

Comment: @PetruGardea Problem could be with the parser ? I was using an online parser to check. I dont know what else to use.

Comment: @PetruGardea No, this is just practice document. I have posted them as an edit. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that's not working is the schema location attribute's namespace. The XML Schema Instance namespace is:

`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`

instead of:

`http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` (you put a **c** in *w3c*)

For the given XML, the error is

`The 'http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance:schemaLocation' attribute is not declared.`

Comment: I didnt get this part `The 'http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance:schemaLocation' attribute is not declared.` What is it ? No online tutorial or book seems to have that attribute. Please elaborate :)